# Can't install ruby-debug-ide on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, windows-7

I'm running netbeans 6.8 on windows 7 pro (x64) with the [bitnami stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) and I'm using ruby 1.8.7-p72.  Note: I can't change the version of ruby I am using because I am working with a team, this is a college project and we have only 3 weeks left before we have to hand it in.  Changing the version of ruby at this time would be too much work I think.

I can't debug my code with the IDE. It says I must have the fast-debugger installed but I cannot install it. When I try through the gui I get the following message:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR: Error installing ruby-debug-ide: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

"C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/bin/ruby.exe" mkrf_conf.rb Building native extensions. This could take a while...

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.8 for inspection. Results logged to C:/Program Files/BitNami RubyStack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.8/ext/gem_make.out
```

I have tracked the problem down to a gcc not being installed... I have installed cygwin but I'm not sure what I am doing and it's still not working...

Anyone know how to fix this problem? (BTW- I have already done a lot of googling on this)

Comment: http://www.rubytips.org/2011/12/20/installing-ruby-on-windows-7-ruby-1-9-x-guide/

Comment: This solved the problem for me http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/view/20-fix-fast-debugger-ruby-debug-ide-on-windows-7 Also useful pdf - there is a list of gems on page 6 for debuger http://csc.columbusstate.edu/woolbright/class/wkenna.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in the end by installing ruby using the windows installer from here:

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer to be the easiest for me:

http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit

Answer (score 0):

My successful way to install fast-debugger for Netbeans 6.8

Download http://files.rubyforge.vm.bytemark.co.uk/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-base-0.10.3-mswin32.gem

Open Your Netbeans -> Tools -> Ruby Gems and tab New Gems ... then Instal Local and choose what U downloaded before.

After installing ruby-debug gem just close and restart Your Netbeans IDE. You'll see ruby-debug-ide gem installed automatically by NB IDE

Comment: Yeah I was missing the gcc which comes with the windows installer from rubyforge.  I was using the bitnami rubystack which does not include the rubydev kit or a gcc.